# Unit-testing for compile errors with C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, compiler-errors

I've written a Matrix class, and checked that it disallowed multiplication of matrices of incompatible sizes using C++ exceptions. I wrote unit tests to check that behavior, and they are expecting exception to be thrown.

Now I'm changing the Matrix size from being a runtime variable to a template parameter. If I'll be able to do that correctly, the code that will try to multiply matrices of wrong sizes won't even compile.

It would seem that now these unit tests are redundant. However, since I don't know how I'll change my code in the future, and what will break, I still want to implement tests for this. If before I expected my tests to throw specific exceptions at specific places, now I want my test to throw specific compile errors at specific places.

What's the best way to do that? I would imagine some sort of mechanism based on Makefile and shell scripting that would wait for a specific error codes — or should I try something else? Is this idea a common practice or complete madness?

**Edit**: Of course, "Unit tests" isn't a fitting name for this kind of mechanism, I know that, but for now, I just can't think of a better way. There are already three comment authors who spent their valuable time and effort explaining to me what unit tests are and what they aren't. Unfortunately, while being technically true, this doesn't help to solve an actual problem at hand here.

**Edit 2**: This is BDD scenario that I want to test for:

- **Given** two matrices of sizes 2x2 and 3x3
- **When** the user tries to multiply them
- **Then** he gets an *error*

Before, that *error* was runtime error, and it testing for it was trivial. But now I it became a compile time error, and I don't see how I can keep automatically testing this scenario and confirming, on every commit (I have unit tests in my git hooks) that it still gives me an error.

Comment: Unit tests are for detecting run time errors. Compilers are for detecting compile time errors.

Comment: Unit tests don't detect runtime errors. Unit tests check that expected runtime errors are detected by program itself or it's runtime. The tool I'm looking for (you're right, unit test isn't the best name for it) wouldn't detect compile errors, but would check that compiler detects them.

Comment: Unit tests should test black box functions whose implementations internally can change, so that you can verify that modifying the internals haven't broken its functionality. I would suggest making implementation-independent APIs for your matricies. A function like `bool canMultiply(Matrix & a, Matrix & b)` can use whatever it wants internally, and is verifiable with unit testing.

Comment: Unit tests are testing things that can be compiled. You can of course write some kinds of tests that test that you can (or can not) compile some code - they aren't unit tests in the strict meaning of the sense [unless your "unit" is a compiler, and most people/organisations don't write their own compiler].

Comment: It would seem to me if template-arguments are being used for your matrix sizes as opposed to runtime-arguments, compile-time validation is covered, as you can define the operations as dependent on the argument deduction itself. I.e, given a matrix `NxM` and another `MxO`, a `template<size_t N, size_t M> Matrix` would/could have a member `operator*` that would be `template<size_t O> Matrix<N,O> operator *(const Matrix<M,O>& m)`. In other words, if your dimensions are template-argument based, you should get compile-time validation for free. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. However, I have some mechanism to ensure that I won't break this compile-time validation in future commits, that's what unit tests are for. If M * N shouldn't compile, but suddenly starts to compile, I want the tests to inform me about it.

For me, that's the point of unit tests — you're not writing them for now, you're writing them for half a year later.

Comment: It seems like you're asking how to test the compiler and not your code. Why would N*M not compile today but suddenly start compiling 6 months from now? The only answer - the compiler itself changed behavior.

If you're just checking for compile errors, won't actually compiling new code do just that?

Answer (score 1):

It's harmless to keep your "unit" test, even if the new `template` style of code makes it "impossible" to mismatch matrix's at run time.  You may still have a bug that gets through to run time and, as you say, the code could change again.

If you're using `gcc`, `gcc` uses [DejaGnu](http://www.gnu.org/software/dejagnu/) to test itself. That should be robust enough to detect `gcc` compilation errors.

Comment: But if I keep it as it is, the runtime error becomes compile error, and I can't run my unit tests at all, because they don't compile. While compile error is desired result, that I want to check for, I want to check for while still having the ability to run all the rest of my unit tests. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Move your unit tests into scriopts that expect compile errors.  Use Python or make/bash

Comment: Expecting C++ compile errors is kinda hard — may be you know of some framework to implement some tests?

Comment: If you're using gcc, gcc uses [DejaGnu](http://www.gnu.org/software/dejagnu/) to ttest itself.  That should be rebust at detecting gcc comile errors

Comment: It seems that DejaGnu is a great answer — why don't you include it into your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @golergka That's great - edited answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't yet have enough Rep to comment on @Paul Evans' answer so please tell me if I should've just not answered.

@Paul Evans recommends DejaGnu and I support that choice.
However if you want to produce more intelligible compile errors (template compile errors tend to get messy) you could use `static_asserts`.

They are standard since c++11 (though you should check if your compiler can use them) and are akin to traditional asserts, only they are checked at compile time and can display a custom error message.

Here's the documentation if you want to check them out : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert